# form tabbing skips <button>

Tags: forms, tabs

is there a reason Firefox and Safari (on my Mac) are skipping over the  element when I tab between fields in this form?

<form>
    <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" tabindex=1/>
    <button id="launch" tabindex=2>do it!</button>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex=3></textarea>
</form>

I shouldn't have to put tabindex in, but even with it it skips the button. I have seen documentation that button elements should accept tabindex.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me in Chrome on Linux, so it might not be a problem with your HTML.

One guess: Mac OS by default does **not** make buttons focusable with Tab-- only text boxes and lists. Maybe Firefox and Safari are merely respecting this setting. You can [change it in the System Preferences](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/10/use-tab-to-switch-between-dialog-buttons.html).

Comment: thanks, too bad there's no way to do it for other users. makes it hard to design a friendly interface if they can't tab to a button without changing their system prefs.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OSX makes you actually turn on tabbing manually on non text input elements at the OS level.

to turn on windows style 'full keyobard access' :

On OS X ~10.6

- Open System Preferences
- Go to Keyboard & Mouse
- Select All controls for Full keyboard access

On OS X 10.9

- Open System Preferences
- Go to Keyboard
- Go to Shortcuts Tab
- Select All controls for Full keyboard access